# Flash contextmenu

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a problem with the following Flash AS3-code:
When I change "Delete1" to "Delete", the menu item disappears.
When I call it anything else but delete, then it reappears.
Why? It also occurs when I comment out hideBuiltInItems...

```
// create new context menu
var mymenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
mymenu.hideBuiltInItems(); // hide items like Zoom, Play, Loop etc

// create new menu item and add it to the right click menu
var frame2item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Delete1");
frame2item.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, doFrame2);
mymenu.customItems.push(frame2item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation of ContextMenuItem](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html) (Link broken as of 10-29-14). You can't use Delete. It's probably a waste of time to circumvent it; consider renaming it something more specific, like "Delete Ash Diffusers". From the documentation:

> The following captions are not allowed, but the words may be used in conjunction with other words to form a custom caption (for example, although "Paste" is not allowed, "Paste tastes great" is allowed):
>
> - Save
> - Zoom In
>
> [...]
>
> - Delete